# How do i select the inverse of this query?

Tags: mysql, select, inverse

How do I select the inverse of this query, and why are my attempts failing...

Query to reverse:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
where (category_id is null and product_id is null) or request_path like '%Portal%';
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
where 
(category_id is not null and product_id is not null)
and request_path not like '%Portal%';
```

When I try to do count(*) on the results of each and add them together I do not get the total count(*) for every row.  It is always less than the total, so I know that I'm not selecting the inverse.  I also can't prove i'm not duping the selection.

Assume that category_id and product_id can be integers, and request_path is never string.empty or null.

I'm a .net programmer. I could probably do this in linq pretty easily, but i'm fixing up a mysql database. Straight SQL has always been my Achilles heel.

Comment: You didn't reverse `category_id is not null` **and** `product_id is not null`. Make it `category_id is not null OR product_id is not null`.

Comment: And there it is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws - But you can also simply use `where not (initial_condition)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transfering [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to SQL you would get the following rules:

```
NOT (a AND b) = NOT a OR  NOT b
NOT (a OR  b) = NOT a AND NOT b
```

That is why you need to replace `and` with `or`

```
where (category_id is not null or product_id is not null)
  and request_path not like '%Portal%'
```

But I would write it the following way:

```
where coalesce(category_id, product_id) is not null
  and request_path not like '%Portal%'
```

**Update**

Trinimons comment is correct: If the `request_path` can contain NULLs, the correct inversion of

```
request_path like '%Portal%'
```

should be

```
(request_path not like '%Portal%' or request_path is null)
```

because `null not like 'anything'` will return NULL.

Comment: There is one issue though: what  happens for rows where `request_path` is `null`? `null` values are neither `like 'something'` nor `not like 'something'`.See http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/markc/archive/2009/06/08/60929.aspx